# How do you compare two randomly generated lists to find elements in common

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that writes two lists of five numbers between 0-9. I need the program to compare the lists to find how many numbers the lists have in common, but I'm not sure how.

Edit: I just need the program to write the amount of numbers in common, I don't need the numbers themselves

```
import random

X = 0

while X<2000:

    House_deal = [random.randint(0,9) for House_deal in range(5)]
    Player_deal = [random.randint(0,9) for House_deal in range(5)]
    print("House numbers: ", House_deal)
    print("Player numbers: ", Player_deal)
    print(" ")
    X += 1
```

Comment: Do you want to count the repeated elements? Say you have two 7 in both list, should the result contains 7 twice?

Comment: Yes, is the were two 7's in each list, I would like that to count as 2 numbers in common. However, if one list contained one 7, and the other contained two, I would like that to count as one number in common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution similar to others already posted, but using [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import random
from collections import Counter

for _ in range(2000):
    House_deal = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(5)]
    Player_deal = [random.randint(0,9) for _ in range(5)]

    hc = Counter(House_deal)
    pc = Counter(Player_deal)
    common = hc.keys() & pc.keys() #get the intersection of both keys
    counts = 0
    for cel in common:
        counts += min(hc[cel], pc[cel])

    print("House numbers: ", House_deal)
    print("Player numbers: ", Player_deal)
    print("Common numbers: ", counts)
```

I also changed the `while` loop into a `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, that seems right. I think you can save yourself a little extra looping but taking the intersection of the counter keys: `common = hc.keys() & pc.keys()`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes, it works. I'll edit my answer, seems more linear this way. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we have `l_one` and `l_two` for two randomly generated lists.

```
counter = [0] * 10
answer = 0
for x in l_one:
    counter[x] += 1
for x in l_two:
    if counter[x] > 0:
        counter[x] -= 1
        answer += 1
print(answer)
```

This algorithm works in O(n) compared to O(n^2) solutions posted before.

Comment: I am putting a variant of this answer (a bit more pythonic).

Comment: When did python get the unary `++`  and `--` operators?

Comment: @EdwardAung sure

Comment: @MarkMeyer it did not. The solution needs the edit. You could do it. I do not want get credits for your observation.

Comment: Your solution is smart. I suggest you to you write it in real python and not in pseudocode. You just need to replace the unary operators with `+= 1` and `-= 1`.

Comment: @Valentino thank you! I just did not want to get credits for the @mark-meyer `s note. I guess, he does not plan to edit it any time soon, so I will do it instead.

Comment: It's your answer. You should be the one to fix it. Other's answers should be edited only to fix format, english, readability but preserving the author intent. It's the author who need to fix his answer if it is incorrect. The best other people can do in this case is to leave a comment to let the author know that there is a problem with his answer. And the author is free to accept the advice and fix his answer or not (because people who comments are not right by default).

Comment: @Valentino I will keep this this in mind. Thank you for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function like the ones [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-print-common-elements-two-lists/) and use the len() function to get the number of elements in the list. The functions cast the lists to sets and get the intersections of them, which would be all the elements in common. That way you can also see the elements that are incommon between them if you decide you want to as well, or you can even modify this to subtract one list from the other to get the elements they don't have in common like [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-difference-two-lists/). Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function as follows:

```
def compare(list1 , list2):

    common_list = []

    for i in list1:
        if i in list2:
            common_list.append(i)

print(len(common_list))   # Number of common elements
```

Comment: This will report three twos in common: `compare([1, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2])`, which is not the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Its work:

```
import random
list_one = random.sample(range(9), 4)
list_two = random.sample(range(9), 4)
print(list_one)
print(list_two)
count = 0
for item_one in list_one:
    for item_two in list_two:
        if item_one == item_two:
            count +=1

print(count)
```

Ps.: The instruction `for item_two in list_two:` maybe change by `if item_one in list_two:`, but as you seem to be a beginner, I put it even more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of the previous answer.

```
counter_1 = {k, 0 : k in l_one}
counter_2 = {k, 0 : k in l_two}
answer = 0
for x in l_one:
    counter_1[x] = counter_1[x] + 1
for x in l_two:
    counter_2[x] = counter_2[x] + 1
for x, v1 in counter_1.items():
    v2 = counter_2.get(x, 0)
answer = answer + min (v1, v2)
print(answer)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) data type in Python, and do something like

```
In [1]: from random import randint

In [2]: import random

In [3]: random.seed(123)

In [4]: x = set([randint(0,9) for x in range(5)])

In [5]: y = set([randint(0,9) for x in range(5)])

In [6]: x
Out[6]: {0, 1, 4, 6}

In [7]: y
Out[7]: {0, 1, 6, 8}

In [8]: cnt = len(x & y)    # return the amount of numbers in common, e.g. {0, 1, 6}

In [9]: cnt
Out[9]: 3
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The OP wants to count dupes twice if they appear in both lists. `list_one = [1, 2, 2]` & `list_two = [2, 2, 3]` should report `[2, 2]`.